Failure Case of "drop_swap" Option in alter-foreign-keys-method for Percona's pt-online-schema-change Tool
I am looking at the option called "alter-foreign-keys-method" in the pt-online-schema-change tool where it uses the drop_swap. In the documentation, it says there are 2 risks:

First, for a short time between dropping the original table and renaming the temporary table, the table to be altered simply does not exist, and queries against it will result in an error. Secondly, if there is an error and the new table cannot be renamed into the place of the old one, then it is too late to abort, because the old table is gone permanently.

What I am trying to understand is the second risk where the renaming of the table will fail. According to the MySQL documentation,

RENAME TABLE tbl_name TO new_tbl_name changes internally generated foreign key constraint names and user-defined foreign key constraint names that begin with the string “tbl_name_ibfk_” to reflect the new table name. InnoDB interprets foreign key constraint names that begin with the string “tbl_name_ibfk_” as internally generated names.


Foreign key constraint names that point to the renamed table are automatically updated unless there is a conflict, in which case the statement fails with an error. A conflict occurs if the renamed constraint name already exists. In such cases, you must drop and re-create the foreign keys for them to function properly.

Would this be the only scenario where the rename table will fail? Because I think I can just write a plugin or a script to make sure that no constraint named "tbl_name_ibfk_" exists before pt-online-schema-change tool runs.

Rename table also fails if the table name is too long (the max is 64 characters). Or if another table of the same name already exists. Or if the table has triggers, and you are renaming to move the table into another schema.

Thank you. I can add these checks to make sure rename table will succeed.

Come to think of this, it seems like drop_swap is better than rebuild_constraints because rebuild_constraints seems disastrous if the table has 10 children tables and it needs to alter the foreign keys on those tables. It could cause tons of metadata lock and customers may see lags or errors. This is in comparison with drop_swap where the original table is dropped and the rename operation is done which could probably take 1-2 seconds only. In this specific case, would you agree that drop_swap is better?

Frankly, in 35 years, I've never worked at a company where foreign key constraints were used in production databases. For exactly the reasons you describe. If the production site is busy enough that those issues would cause a problem, then they don't use constraints. If the traffic is light enough that those issues don't cause a problem, then there's no problem (and they probably don't use pt-online-schema-change anyway).
